# Twitter Bootstrap open remote URL programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="modal_window">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h3>Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my html code,

i want to load a remote content into it, let say yahoo.com

I tried

```
$('#modal_window').attr('data-remote', 'http://www.yahoo.com').modal({show:true, remote:true});
```

It shows the normal modal content instead of yahoo loaded into modal. How do i make it to load yahoo.com into the modal window?

http://jsfiddle.net/UXU2K/1/

Thanks

Comment: does it have to do with spelling modal_win vs modal_window?

Comment: nope, it was correct, i misspelled when putting it here. thanks for noticing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two ways to load remote data via Javascript is either from AJAX or by setting the url of an iFrame.  An iFrame is for when you want to load an entire website.  I'm going to assume you don't want that.  You're using jQuery, so here's the documentation for their ajax method http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Here's the code to load remote data using jQuery's ajax method:

```
    $.ajax({

       url: 'http://www.yahoo.com',
       type: 'GET',
       success: function(data) {

          $('#modal_body').append(html);

       }

    });
```

By the way, if you are loading HTML (opposed to plain text) and want to inject that into  the modal_win element, use the following code in the success method instead of what I have above:

`$(html).appendTo('#modal_body');`

Answer (score 0):

Passing in `remote: true` is invalid syntax since you're setting the data attribute. If you remove it you will see this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.yahoo.com/. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

It will work if the page is on the same domain as your site. Otherwise, you will need to use an iFrame, but it depends on your application.

Comment: In addition, Yahoo may have scripts in place to prevent you from doing this.